# matplotlib histogram in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have load a time series dataset in pandas(date/time and kwh) and I would like to build a histogram.I'm confused with the syntax.I used this(plt.hist(data.kwh)) but the result wasn't good.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite unclear, please add some more information. A few lines of source code are often better than 1000 words :)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally when you build your histogram you should also use the "bins" parameter to make enough bins to hold your data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import ceil

# Load data as data.kwh

spacing = 10 # size on x axis of the bin to aim for
bins = ceil((data.kwh.max() - data.kwh.min()) / spacing)

plt.hist(data.kwh, bins=bins)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matplotlib.pyplot.hist(samples, bins = 101)
```

where samples is an array and  bins is the number of bins you want in your  histogram.

Alternatively, you can use pylab to  performm this task:

```
pylab.hist(samples, bins = 101)
```